# Weird Insect on Window, SW London

Tags: entomology

Insect is avout 5 cm long, antenna to tail, was on a windows. Tried to transfer to white paper, but it moved to a wall[[image: seen on wall][1]]

Answer (score 4):

The overall appearance and shape points to a [mayfly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayfly) (in Ephemeroptera). However, I don’t know what species it is.